# How to match pattern that has unspecified number of 2-digit hex numbers separated by a single space?

Tags: python, regex

Match pattern that has unspecified number of 2-digit hex numbers separated by a single space.

```
0000000: 4B 0B 69 00 04 00 00 00 EE 03 00 00 00 00 00 00  abcdefg
==> 4B 0B 69 00 04 00 00 00 EE 03 00 00 00 00 00 00

12345 4B 0B 69 00 04 00 00 00 EE 03 00 00   01 02
==> 4B 0B 69 00 04 00 00 00 EE 03 00 00

# (because there are more than one space between 00 and 01)

12: 4B 0B 69 00 04 00 00 00 EE 2
==> 4B 0B 69 00 04 00 00 00 EE

5 4B 0B 69 00 04 00 3
==> 4B 0B 69 00 04 00

ZZ 4B 0B 69 00 04 00 DD MN
==> 4B 0B 69 00 04 00 DD

# Because ZZ and MN are not hex numbers
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lookbehind ought to solve this. You're looking for- `\b(?<! {2})([\da-f]{2})(?= {1})` (with insensitive flag)

Here's a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/n4aIX0/2)

### Explanation

```regex
\b(?<! {2})([\da-f]{2})(?= {1})
```

- `\b` - matches the word boundary, this is mostly just to make sure it doesn't match stuff like 45 from the 12345 in `12345 4B 0B 69 00 04 00 00 00 EE 03 00 00   01 02`
- `(?<! {2})` - this makes sure the match **does not** have 2 spaces to its left
- `([\da-f]{2})` - captures hex numbers of 2 digits
- `(?= {1})` - Checks for a singular space afterwards

### Code

In python, you can use `re.findall` with `re.I` flag to find all the hex numbers in a given string.

```py
import re

match = re.findall(r'\b(?<! {2})([\da-f]{2})(?= {1})', '0000000: 4B 0B 69 00 04 00 00 00 EE 03 00 00 00 00 00 00  abcdefg', flags=re.I)
print(match)
```

### Output

```
['4B',
 '0B',
 '69',
 '00',
 '04',
 '00',
 '00',
 '00',
 'EE',
 '03',
 '00',
 '00',
 '00',
 '00',
 '00',
 '00']
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you could do it with list comprehension utilizing `hexdigits` from the `string` library. Not sure how to accomplish with regex:

```
import string
s = 'ZZ 4B 0B 69 00 04 00 DD MN'
s = re.sub(r'\s\s.*', '', s)
' '.join([i for i in s.split(' ') if len(i) == 2 if i[0:1] in string.hexdigits])

'4B 0B 69 00 04 00 DD'
```

Basically, it loops through the string to check if both are hexdigits.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the difficult part is that the above list comprehension cannot handle cases like `5 4B 0B 69 00 04 00 3` since it gives result `5 4B 0B 69 00 04 00 3` but what is desired is `4B 0B 69 00 04 00`

Comment: @CodingNow see my updated answer with `if len(i) == 2` Shoot, unfortunately, it wouldn't keep the `00` as well, since that is duped. I'll try to think of a more robust solution.

Comment: you don't consider 1 or more spaces, this info is lost due to the `split()`

Comment: @riov8 Good catch, I have replace `split()` with `split(' ')`

Comment: this will not improve because `split()` and `split(' ')` are the same here, your code will fail on the second example

Comment: @rioV8 Apologies, I looked at it again and you are correct. I included `s = re.sub(r'\s+\s+.*', '', s)` in my answer.

Comment: `\s+` and `\s+\s+` are "equivalent", the second `\s+` has no purpose, better to use `\s{2,}`, or `\s\s+`. it is confusing of what you want

Comment: Thanks @rioV8 I did not know that :) Need to brush up on my regex skills. Actually, when I change `\s+\s+` to `\s+`, I get a different output.

Comment: I changed my comment to suggest better alternatives

Answer (score 1):

My 2-cents: `(?:^|\s)([0-9a-fA-F]{2}(?:\s|$))+`

https://regex101.com/r/I0gQlU/2

- `(?:^|\s)`: either start of the string or a white space
- `[0-9a-fA-F]{2}`: 2 hexadecimal digits
- `(?:\s|$)`: either ends with a space or end of string
- `+`: a number of times (1 or more)